# Using Statifier with CMake

Tags: cmake

How can I use

tool like http://statifier.sourceforge.net/ statifier to make library static ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a `custom_target` to work on your `library` or `executable` to do special stuff.

If you want to change the linker-command in cmake the lowest level I'm aware of is to overwrite the `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE`-variable (for C it is `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE`) to use your own linker. If you do that, pay attention to the special `<>`-fields in that variable. See [here](http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Build_rules) for all variables. The section below (Expansion Rules) shows the special 'tags' which can be used inside cmake's Build-variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have in my main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# statifier determine (http://statifier.sourceforge.net/) for linux
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
set(FOOBAR-HAS-STATIFIER false)

if (UNIX)

  find_program(STATIFIER_EXE NAMES "statifier")

  if (NOT STATIFIER_EXE STREQUAL STATIFIER_EXE-NOTFOUND)

    set(FOOBAR-HAS-STATIFIER true)

    macro(MAKE_STATIC_EXE _static_exe_out)
      foreach (_target ${ARGN})
        set(_shared_exe "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_target}")
        set(_static_exe "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${_target}-static/${_target}")
        add_custom_command(POST_BUILD
          OUTPUT ${_static_exe}
          COMMAND ${STATIFIER_EXE} --set=LD_BIND_NOW=yes ${_shared_exe} ${_static_exe}
          DEPENDS ${_shared_exe}
          )
        SET(${_static_exe_out} ${${_static_exe_out}} ${_static_exe})
      endforeach()
    endmacro()

  else ()

    message ("statifier (http://statifier.sourceforge.net/) not found. Can not build setup for unix")

  endif ()

endif ()
```

and later in main app `CMakeLists.txt`

```
##
## static foobar
##
if (FOOBAR-HAS-STATIFIER)
  make_static_exe(FOOBAR-STATIC-dynstat dynstat)
  message("${FOOBAR-STATIC-dynstat}")
endif ()
```

After a succesfull build a have in the build dir a `foobar` and a static `foobar-static`executeable.